# Raise error in ternary statement in python, without using classic if/else syntax

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it possible in python to **directly** raise an error in a ternary statement?

As in:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.random.rand(200, 5, 5)

y = (y[:, None] if y.ndim == 1 
    else y if y.ndim == 2 
    else raise ValueError('`y` must be given as a 1D or 2D array.'))
```

Of course it is possible to do this with a simple if/elif/else statement. Thus I'm asking specifically for a solution using a "one-line" ternary statement.

Just for clarification:
I know that ternary statements are not intended to raise errors and that it is not *good style* according to PEP8 etc.. I am just asking **if it is possible at all**.

Comment: i think people who will read this code will curse you, IMHO.

Comment: @BearBrown Why? Imho ternary statements are a great tool to simplify code. Of course raising errors is probably not what they are intended to do and I never used them to raise an error until now, **but** it seems like a quite... "interesting"... way to write a short expression.

Comment: just read the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and try to analasy your code for example with the [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/)

Comment: @Scotty1- You are right. This syntax was never intended to be used for raising errors. It was intended for `target = normal_value if expected_conditions() else fallback_value`.

Comment: @BearBrown Thanks for pointing that out. I use pylint and try to comply with PEP8 all of the time. And as I said, I know that ternary statements are not meant to raise errors. I did not want to start a discussion about if it is good style or not, since I know it is not. Thus I **specifically** ask, if it is **possible at all**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plain simple technical answer: NO, it is not possible - as you probably found out by yourself, it yields a SyntaxtError (`raise` is a statement and the ternary op only supports expressions).

Comment: I think you wrote the best explanation: statements cannot be used in expressions, ternary op is expression, `raise` is a statement, ergo: `raise` cannot be used in ternary ops.

Comment: Yep, a short but exact explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple helper function:

```
>>> def my_raise(ex): raise ex

>>> x = 1 if False else my_raise(ValueError('...'))
ValueError: ...
```

Comment: This is a nice solution if I have multiple ternary statements where I need to raise an error. But if I have only one, this is quite much equivalent to raising the error in an explicit if/else statement.

Answer (score -1):

You probably shouldn't do it, but you can call an expression that always causes an exception:

```py
y = "foo" if condition else int(None)
```

This will assign `foo` to `y` if `condition=True` and will raise a `TypeError` otherwise:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```